# Deploy springboot application and react application to ubuntu server

Tags: spring, reactjs, nginx, apache2, web-deployment

I created a simple application, which consists of a reactjs frontend and a spring boot app as backend. It works fine on my local environment; with the react app running on port 3000, and the spring app running on port 9000.

I am trying to host this application in the staging environment. I want to host both the reactjs and spring boot app on a ubuntu server that I have on digitalocean. I have managed to deploy the reactjs frontend using nginx and now I want to deploy the backend using apache2.

I am having difficulty deploying the Spring boot app. I have generated a WAR file.

In my react application I call the backend spring app to serve as the api to the frontend to the browser. I have set up apache app to listen on port 9000 see below:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
   ServerName 46.101.34.160
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot 
/var/www/html/BackEndBookingAndCollections
   </VirtualHost>
```

My configuration details for the frontend goes as follows in the file;

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/FEBookingAndCollections

The contents is the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/FEBookingAndCollections/build;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name 46.101.34.160;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/bookings/ {
                proxy_pass http://46.101.34.160:9000/api/bookings;
        }
}
```

In google chrome's browser I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :9000/api/bookings:1
```

Comment: are you using tomcat inside apache to deploy spring war ?

Comment: @underscore no, I have only installed apache2 onto the ubuntu server. I then pointed the document root to the directory where the war file is residing.

Comment: how does war file being deploying itself without a server ?

Comment: I ssh into the server and I copy the war file from my local computer into the server machine. I then configure apache2 to read the class path to the war file

Comment: @benbrick @underscore you don't need to install tomcat or apache2 to serve the backend. Since it's a spring-boot app, you can leverage the embedded server (tomcat by default) to serve the backend. If you have `spring-boot-started-web` as a dependency and all related configs, you can just use `java -jar artifact.war`

Comment: @MadhuBhat how do you manage your command all the time ? tomcat and apache do it for them

Comment: spring boot is started by java -jar springthing.jar - it comes with a embedded webserver (you can configure it to whatever webserver you want, but since Spring is InversionOfControl you don't let the webserver host your app but the app host&contoll the webserver!

Answer (score 1):

With spring boot, you don't have to use external Tomcat. You can package your app to jar with embedded tomcat. You can find more info here - https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy war file without a server. Just follow bellow steps

1) install tomcat

2) find tomcat webapps path ( /usr/local/tomcat/webapps )

3) copy your war file to webapps. ( use scp )

4) make sure your war file and tomcat listen on same port. 8080 or 9000

5) proxy your api though apache

Comment: I thought that apache2 is a server. Because I have apache2 installed on the Ubuntu server to serve the backend application.

Comment: yes. apache is a server. but when you are working with java. you have to use tomcat wrapper. learn about them letter.

Comment: You don't need to install tomcat. Can use the embedded tomcat that spring boot provides.

Comment: @MadhuBhat it's make no sense. How do you manage the command ?

Comment: @MadhuBhat it's home work practice. not a good for production environment.

Comment: @underscore I suppose you are not aware of leveraging spring boot's embedded server. It is very much used in production globally. It helps in having a microservice architecture.

Comment: @underscore it's not about managing the command. You can just have an init script/config to run the app using nohup. Obviously you need the config to make sure that the app runs always in the background and starts on system booting. Bottomline is, it's very much used in production globally, and it's one of the main features of `spring boot`. Please read about it for more information.

Comment: @underscore what do you mean by proxy your api through apache. Do that mean config your api through apache?